# Where is the best place to propose ideas for Monero

Tags: monero-community, community

*What is the best way to propose ideas to the Monero community?*

*GitHub, official forum, Reddit, IRC, here?*

I know that tech discussions are on GitHub, but I don't know which is the best place to propose general ideas for Monero.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#monero on Freenode IRC is probably the best sounding place. Or #monero-dev on Freenode if this is about monero development itself. #monero-research-lab for ideas to do with the theory or R&D.

Note that many people have a funny view of what's about monero development. They think if it involves them using a compiler (or sometimes just involves them), it's about development. That's not correct. If in doubt, try #monero. You'll be redirected if needed.